# Use of coupling capacitors in transistor biasing

Tags: mosfet, capacitor, oscillator, square

I'm trying to use oscillator circuit to switch on the MOSFET and using coupling capacitors to isolate the DC biasing.
Below is my circuit and graph
[image]

[image]

I'm not able to understand the DC biasing here. Getting output around 20V. Need help to understand the circuit.

Comment: MOSFET is acting as a switch. No need of biasing in this case.

Comment: You don’t appear to have any coupling capacitors.  What feature of the output do you not understand, and what output do you desire?

Comment: I'm connecting the output to window comparator. At mosfet output I'm not able to generate 24V to comparator input. For representation I have connected to 6.81K to ground to measure the output

Comment: the only capacitor I see is the degeneration one in the inverting terminal

Comment: I have "C5" (2.2uF) capacitor connected at mosfet drain

Answer (score 1):

Here's the equivalent circuit of your output:-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffLKuN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Initially the FET is on (M1 closed) so C1 is discharged and has 0 volts across it. Now consider what happens when M1 opens:- C1 momentarily acts like a short circuit, so R15 is effectively in series with R17||R18 creating   a voltage divider with ratio of 4.68k / (1k + 4.68k) = 0.824. Therefore the output voltage will momentarily jump to 24 * 0.824 = 19.8 V.

However the capacitor now charges through the resistors, causing a voltage to develop across it which makes the output voltage sag.

A little while later M1 closes again and pulls the input side of C1 to ground. Since C1 has a voltage across it the output now goes a little bit negative, causing C1 to discharge through R17||R18 (very slowly because the voltage is small). Over time this trend continues until the charge and discharge cycles equalize, with the output going from ~ -10.8 V to +10.8 V and C1 having ~ 10.8 V across it.

You can see the beginnings of this in your graph. If you run the simulation for a long time (eg. 100ms) you will see that the capacitor has removed the DC bias from the output, with the [RC time constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC_time_constant) that you would expect (average of C1 * (R15 + R17||R18) when charging and C1 * R17||R18 when discharging) of ~ 11.4 ms.

If you plot the voltage across C1 you should see something like this:-

[image]

Comment: Yes. Now I can understand the circuit but when I measure the voltage across the C1, I get very low voltage instead of -11V to +11V. I think I need to run the simulation for some time, may be upto 100ms to observe the voltage across C1. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: Yes. Look at the graph I posted, it takes nearly 100ms to reach its final value.